# Android WebView Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': error playing mp3 file

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mediaplayer

In my HTML file the when HTML is loading it plays mp3 file in background.
but its not playing that file its give following error.
Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement':

Answer (score 0):

```
got the solution.
it occurs because of I am playing audio file without making any click or not doing any action in webview. to overcome this need to set below property to webview

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) 
{
   mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
}
```